# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

There was a need to deploy an old project. Corrected gulpfile.js a bit so that the assembly started running, it came across an error:

```
[21:12:57] Finished 'html:build' after 71 ms
[21:12:57] Starting 'js:build'...
[21:12:57] 'js:build' errored after 15 ms
[21:12:57] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, 
ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined
at Function.from (buffer.js:207:11)
at new Buffer (buffer.js:182:17)
at G:\firststep\odc-client-app-2019-clean-html\node_modules\gulp-rigger\index.js:20:29
at Rigger.<anonymous> (G:\firststep\odc-client-app-2019-clean- 
html\node_modules\rigger\index.js:719:9)
at Rigger.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Rigger.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
at G:\firststep\odc-client-app-2019-clean-html\node_modules\rigger\index.js:252:16
at G:\firststep\odc-client-app-2019-clean-html\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:232:13
at G:\firststep\odc-client-app-2019-clean-html\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:113:21
at G:\firststep\odc-client-app-2019-clean-html\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:24:16
[21:12:57] 'build' errored after 87 ms
[21:12:57] 'default' errored after 89 ms
```

gulpfile.js:

```js
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
 watch = require('gulp-watch'),
 prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
 uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
 cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
 sass = require('gulp-sass'),
 sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
 rigger = require('gulp-rigger'),
 imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
 pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
 rimraf = require('rimraf'),
 connect = require('gulp-connect'),
 opn = require('opn'),
 notify = require('gulp-notify'),
 copy = require('gulp-copy'),
 plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
 less = require('fd-gulp-less');

var path = {
 build: {
  html: 'build/',
  js: 'build/assets/sys/js/',
  css: 'build/assets/sys/css/',
  img: 'build/assets/sys/img/',
  fonts: 'build/assets/sys/fonts/'
 },
 src: {
  html: 'src/*.html',
  js: 'src/js/main.js',
  style: 'src/style/style.less',
  img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
  fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
 },
 watch: {
  html: 'src/**/*.html',
  js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
  style: 'src/style/**/*.less',
  img: 'src/img/**/*.*',
  fonts: 'src/fonts/**/*.*'
 },
 clean: './build'
};

var server = {
 host: 'localhost',
 port: '1495'
};

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
 rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
 connect.server({
  host: server.host,
  port: server.port,
  livereload: true
 });
});

gulp.task('webserver-stop', function() {
 connect.server({
  host: server.host,
  port: server.port,
  livereload: true
 });
 connect.serverClose();
});

gulp.task('openbrowser', function() {
 opn( 'http://' + server.host + ':' + server.port + '/build' );
});

gulp.task('html:build', function () {
 return gulp.src(path.src.html)
  .pipe(plumber({
   errorHandler: function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
   }
  }))
  .pipe(rigger())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
  .pipe(notify('HTML: Done!'))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
 gulp.src(path.src.js)
  .pipe(plumber({
   errorHandler: function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
   }
  }))
  .pipe(rigger())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
  .pipe(notify('JS: Done!'))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('style:build', function () {
 gulp.src(path.src.style)
  .pipe(plumber({
   errorHandler: function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
   }
  }))
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(prefixer())
  .pipe(cssmin())
  // .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
  .pipe(notify('CSS: Done!'))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('image:build', function () {
 gulp.src(path.src.img)
  .pipe(imagemin({
   progressive: true,
   svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}, {cleanupIDs: false}],
   use: [pngquant()],
   interlaced: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))
  .pipe(notify('IMG: Done!'))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', function() {
 gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
  .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts))
  .pipe(notify('FONTS: Done!'));
});

gulp.task('build', gulp.series(
 'html:build',
 'js:build',
 'style:build',
 'fonts:build',
 'image:build'
));

gulp.task('watch', function(){
 watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('html:build');
 });
 watch([path.watch.style], function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('style:build');
 });
 watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('js:build');
 });
 watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('image:build');
 });
 watch([path.watch.fonts], function(event, cb) {
  gulp.start('fonts:build');
 });
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build', 'webserver-stop', 'webserver', 'watch', 'openbrowser'));
gulp.task('start', gulp.series('build', 'webserver-stop', 'webserver', 'watch'));
gulp.task('stop', gulp.series('webserver-stop'));
//gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch', 'openbrowser']);
```

I tried `npm install jquery --save-dev` because I found such tips in Google, but it didn’t help, and also tried `bower install jquery --save-dev`, because there is a bower in the project, but it also didn’t help. How do I fix an assembly?
sorry for bad eng.

Answer (score 1):

i just had the same error. The source of error was gulp-rigger package. try to remove it and see if that works.

p.s. i replaced gulp-rigger with [gulp-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-include)

Comment: spasiba! I abandoned the project and can no longer try your solution :(

Answer (score 1):

this error indicates about some error your files. the gulp-rigger can't find some files in your project. Since gulp-rigger wrote 'js:build', check paths to jquery, popper, and other includes in main.js. have you created main.js before gulp start?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the directory where my project was located contained parentheses. I removed them and everything worked.